# How to use Tailwind Nested Declarations with postcss.config.js without require()

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss

I'm trying to use nested declarations in Tailwind, so, in their [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting) they show `postcss.config.js` using `require()` from CommonJS:

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ]
}
```

I need the same behavior, but in another format, **not** using the `require()` format, example:

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install `postcss-import` via npm/yarn and then change your `postcss.config.js` to:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    }
}
```

Also: When you use `tailwindcss` to transpile your CSS make sure you have the `--postcss` flag enabled.

Comment: what do you mean we should update start script by adding --postcss:true like that ? Thanks

Comment: TY man, after *--postcss* works ;)

Comment: same here, adding --postcss to `"watch": "npx tailwindcss -i ./tailwind.css -o ./_SITE/_/css/tw.css --watch --postcss",` in package.json fixed tailwind not processing nested rules. Thanks